# Hey, I'm trying to make these links under desc clickable. I'm not entirely sure how to do it though, can someone take a look?

Tags: javascript, next.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaX74.jpg)

I'm new to JS so I am finding it a little complicated to get it set up. Can someone please fix? I'm sure its super easy but just can't crack it. Thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

Here is next.js Links [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link), check it. Should be something like this

```
import Link from 'next/link'

const List = ({data}) => {
  return (
    <ul>
        {data.map((item) => {
            return (
                <li key={item.name}>
                    <Link href={item.desc[0].p}>
                      <a>{item.name}</a>
                    </Link>
                  </li>
            )
        })}
    </ul>
  )
}
```